# Not able to get the filename outside the internalStorage in android?

Tags: android

Below is my code.What i am trying to achieve select a file or image from filemanager and displaying it's name in the textView. But the problem is when i click on button internalStorage opens and everythning works fine. But if i don't use internalStorage and if i use recent folder or any other folder outside the inernalStorage then i am not able to get the filename as expected but i can select the image from there. What can i do to achieve this?

```
mBrowseButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent browseIntent = new Intent();
        browseIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        browseIntent.setType("*/*");
        startActivityForResult(browseIntent,REQUESTCODE_PICK_FILE);
    }
});


if (requestCode == REQUESTCODE_PICK_FILE
        && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
    if(data != null) {
        Uri fileUri = data.getData();
        result = fileUri.getPath();
        File img = new File(result);
        result = img.getName();
        System.out.println("file path is " + result);
        mEditText.setText(result);

        if(!arrayList.contains(result)) {
            arrayList.add(result);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 Cursor c = context.getContentResolver().query(fileUri, null, null, null, null);
        c.moveToFirst();

        String type = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE));
        String file_name = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
        c.close();
```

Comment: Glad it worked. You can also visit : http://stackoverflow.com/tour to get more information about SO and support me as much as you can.